# Stack Exchange Data Explorer footer lacks links to the newest SE sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, footer

[Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/)'s footer doesn't contain links to the latest launched Stack Exchange sites - Programmers, Unix & Linux and others. Is this intentional or an oversight?

Data Explorer's footer:

[image: Stack Exchange Data Explorer footer]

compared to Stack Overflow's footer:

[image: Stack Overflow footer]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by design.

SEDE is [an independent codebase](http://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer) from all the SE sites, and as such, we have to go in and update things like the footer manually. Currently, that content isn't automatically synchronized at all.

Probably the closest we can get to synchronization is to create the footer dynamically based on the sites loaded into SEDE.

Feel free to submit a patch to do that (see the link above), or the links can simply be updated manually.

**EDIT:** I've [pushed a change](http://code.google.com/r/jseigelis-test/source/detail?r=d096374c3440856c63dd841ff15883f9c5d382cb) with a copy/paste job from Meta SO. No dynamic stuff, just a quick and dirty fix for now.

Comment: This is now live.